# SQL SELECT with JOIN and WHERE clause - selecting one record from two tables

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I got something like this:

```
MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(@"SELECT Pupil.*, Instructor.* 
    FROM Pupil
    INNER JOIN Instructor ON Pupil.email = Instructor.email
    WHERE Pupil.email = '" + userEmail.Text + "'
      and Pupil.password = '" + userPassword.Text + "'", sqlconn);
```

and I need to get a record which is hidden in first or the second table. I checked and I inserted the same data into the second table. This SELECT is showing me the common record but I want only an unique from the first or the second table.

Comment: You should always use parameterized SQL to have your code more clear, avoids conversion issues, and avoids SQL injection attacks.

Comment: You can do a full outer join and then programmatically filter out records that don't have NULL on either side, the records that have NULL from either the left table or right table would be you unique records. Hope thats what you are looking for.

Comment: The question is unclear. How are records hidden in the tables? What does it mean that you want a unique record from the first *or* the second table? Which table do you want a record from? As programmers we tend to look for literal meaning, especially when discussing the code itself, because it's the only way we can communicate. So it's helpful to write the question to be understood from that perspective.

Comment: Ok, hidden means that it's is simply IN the table.

I apologize for an unique phrase. I just wanted to say: I insert data to the first or the second table. How I can type a query which will know when the data won't be on the first, it will need search in the second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comment above I've modified the query. Here are two examples for the example data:

**Pupils**

- Adam@abc.com
- Bob@abc.com

**Instructors**

- Bob@abc.com (note your data structure does actually allows this)
- Chris@abc.com

**Query**

```
/* Adam is a pupil but not an instructor */
select Pupil.*
from Pupil
left join Instructor on Pupil.email = Instructor.email
where Instructor.email is null
  and Pupil.email = 'Adam@abc.com'
union 
select Instructor.*
from Instructor
left join Pupil on Pupil.email = Instructor.email
where Pupil.email is null
  and Instructor.email = 'Adam@abc.com';

/* Chris is an instructor but not a pupil */
select Pupil.*
from Pupil
left join Instructor on Pupil.email = Instructor.email
where Instructor.email is null
  and Pupil.email = 'Chris@abc.com'
union 
select Instructor.*
from Instructor
left join Pupil on Pupil.email = Instructor.email
where Pupil.email is null
  and Instructor.email = 'Chris@abc.com';
```

You can find a working example at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c490c7/28

Comment: I just need to select record from two tables, because it's maybe in first or maybe in second table. That's all.

Comment: I changed my syntax to:


`MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand("select Pupil.* from Pupil left join Instructor on Pupil.email = Instructor.email where Instructor.email is null and Pupil.email = '" + userEmail.Text + "' and Pupil.password = '" + userPassword.Text + "' union select Instructor.* from Instructor left join Pupil on Pupil.email = Instructor.email where Pupil.email is null and Instructor.email = '" + userEmail.Text  + "' and Instructor.password = '" + userPassword.Text + "'", sqlconn);`

and got an unhandled exception occured...

Have you got any ideas?

Comment: I got also: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns